# ncl: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.10: version `libssl.so.10' not found (required by ncl)

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, ncl

This is in reference to running the WRF model in my system. I am trying to run the file plotgrids.ncl to ensure that the domain is in the right location before running geogrid.exe . Running the following command in my terminal(ubuntu)
`ncl util/plotgrids.ncl`
gives me the following error:

`ncl: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.10: version 'libssl.so.10' not found (required by ncl)
ncl: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.10: version 'libcrypto.so.10' not found (required by ncl)`

Answer (score 0):

at one NCL 6.4.0 installation at Ubuntu 10.10 the solution was 
searching a compat-openssl10 package, as 
compat-openssl10-1.0.2j-9.fc26.x86_64.rpm
turn it into a .deb package by doing this steps:

```
apt-get install libdpkg-perl
alien compat-openssl10-1.0.2j-9.fc26.x86_64.rpm
dpkg -i compat-openssl10_1.0.2j-10_amd64.deb

find / -name libssl.so.*
```

will now show it at /usr/lib/ libssl.so.10

NCL will still complain about GLIBC version 
at this case that was solved by editing

```
vi /etc/apt/sources.list
:%s/maverick/wily/g

apt-get update
apt-get install libc6
```

this still shows as 2.15 with

```
ldd --version
```

however now the test works with

```
ng4ex xy01n -clean
```

Answer (score 0):

for Ubuntu 16 please check help given by NCL forum at
mailman.ucar.edu/pipermail/ncl-install/2017-November/thread.html 
as resumed here:

http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html
used Python 3.6 Linux 64-bit (bash installer)

```
cd /home/user/Downloads/
chmod +x Miniconda2-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
./Miniconda2-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
conda -V
```

conda 4.3.30

http://ncl.ucar.edu/Download/conda.shtml

```
conda create -n ncl_stable -c conda-forge ncl=6.4.0 gsl
root@hostname:~# source activate ncl_stable
(ncl_stable) root@hostname:~# ncl -V
```

6.4.0

```
ng4ex xy05n -clean -W png
```

it works!

outside conda (ncl_stable)

```
ng4ex
```

The program 'ng4ex' is currently not installed. You can install it by:

```
sudo su
vi /etc/apt/sources.list
```

add at the end

```
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian/ testing non-free contrib main
```

exit editor

```
apt-get update
apt install libncarg-bin
```